# PAReview.sh error, Expected "switch (...) {\n"; found "switch(...) {\n"

Tags: coding-standards

In my theme's template.php file, I have a custom function as:

```
function _MYTHEME_content_grid($columns = 1) {

  $class = FALSE;
  switch($columns) {

    // No sidebars, just content.
    case 1:{
      $class = 'grid-100';
      break;
      } 

// etc...
```

When I run the code through http://ventral.org/, I get this message in regard to the switch statement line: `switch($columns) {`

```
ERROR | Expected "switch (...) {\n"; found "switch(...) {\n"
```

I googled around but I can't really find anything on this error. My function works perfectly fine though. I'm guessing it's a syntax error but it would seem weird to insert a `;` after the curly brace...

Comment: RajeevK is right, there is no need for curly braces wrapping the case block. Nonetheless, my guess is that the PAReview error is about the need for a white space in front of the term "switch". Well, it is not exactly a need, but a code convention.

Comment: @FranciscoLuz - yes without the curly braces around the `case` block, that too throws an error with PAReview.sh so I added those based on its suggestion... I may end up ignoring this as I got the function from the bootstrap theme and that's already a fully promoted project and I have full commit rights so I could just ignore it but obviously I'm trying to follow best practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says it all.

Put `switch ($columns)` instead of `switch($columns)`

> Control statements should have one space between the control keyword
>   and opening parenthesis, to distinguish them from function calls.

For more info refer [Drupal coding standards](https://drupal.org/coding-standards#controlstruct)

Answer (score 3):

Put simple switch, why put curly braces.

```
    function _MYTHEME_content_grid($columns = 1) {

      $class = FALSE;
      switch($columns) {

        // No sidebars, just content.
        case 1:
          $class = 'grid-100';
          break;
        case 2:
          //something
          break;   

       // etc...
     }
   }
```

Comment: Ironically, without the curly braces around `case`, that too throws an error with PAReview.sh so I added those because of that issue.